# How to iterate properties of two objects dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have two object of same class, I want to update the p2 with fields which are are in Dirty list. So far I managed to write the following code but struggling to get the value of p1 properties. What object should I pass here as parameter to `GetValue` method.

```
Person p1 = new Person();
p1.FirstName = "Test";
Person p2 = new Person();

var allDirtyFields = p1.GetAllDirtyFields();
foreach (var dirtyField in allDirtyFields)
{
  p2.GetType()
    .GetProperty(dirtyField)
    .SetValue(p1.GetType().GetProperty(dirtyField).GetValue());
}     

_context.UpdateObject(p2);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you know that you don't need to retrieve the property for each object?

Type metadata is common to any object of the whole type.

For example:

```
// Firstly, get dirty property informations!
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> dirtyProperties = p2.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
              .Where
              (
                   property => allDirtyFields.Any
                   (
                       field => property.Name == field
                   )
              );

// Then, just iterate the whole property informations, but give the
// "obj" GetValue/SetValue first argument the references "p2" or "p1" as follows:
foreach(PropertyInfo dirtyProperty in dirtyProperties)
{          
       dirtyProperty.SetValue(p2, dirtyProperty.GetValue(p1)); 
}
```

Check that the first parameter of [`PropertyInfo.GetValue(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385.aspx) and [`PropertyInfo.SetValue(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194291.aspx) is the object for which you want to get or set the value of the whole property.

Answer (score 2):

You should try that:

```
foreach (var dirtyField in allDirtyFields)
{
    var prop = p2.GetType().GetProperty(dirtyField);
    prop.SetValue(p2, prop.GetValue(p1));
}
```

It is a better to store `PropertyInfo` instance in a variable, then trying to resolve it twice.

Comment: Thanks, can you please give an example how I can store PropertyInfo for each variable

Comment: Actually, it's already in my code, isn't it? `prop` local variable instead of `p2.GetType().SetValue()` and `p1.GetType().GetValue()` saves one `GetType()` call, which is quite expensive one.

Answer (score 1):

In each iteration, you have to get a reference to the `PropertyInfo`. When you call it's `SetValue` method, you should pass in 2 parameters, the object for which you will set the property and the actual value you are setting. For the latter one, you should invoke the `GetValue` method on the same property, passing in the `p1` object as parameter, i.e. the source for the value.

Try this:

```
foreach (var dirtyField in allDirtyFields)
{
    var p = p2.GetType().GetProperty(dirtyField);
    p.SetValue(p2, p.GetValue(p1));
}
```

I would recommend you to keep the `dirtyField` variables in a dictionary and retrieve the associated `PropertyInfo` object from this dictionary. It should be much faster.
Firstly, declare some static variable in your class:

```
static Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> 
    personProps = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>();
```

Then you may change your method to:

```
foreach (var dirtyField in allDirtyFields)
{
    PropertyInfo p = null;
    if (!personProps.ContainsKey(dirtyField))
    {
        p = p2.GetType().GetProperty(dirtyField);
        personProps.Add(dirtyField, p);
    }
    else
    {
        p = personProps[dirtyField];
    }
    p.SetValue(p2, p.GetValue(p1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass [the instance from which you want to get the property value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx), like so:

```
p1.GetType().GetProperty(dirtyField).GetValue(p1, null)
```

The second parameter, can be used to retrieve a value at a certain index if the property type is indexed.

Answer (score 0):

IIrc you send p1 being the instance that holds the value and null to indicate you're not searching for a specific index value.